Would it be advisable to put the Custom Metadata Type records in a Wrapper Class?
I have a code that is dependent in metadata records. Let's say if my object record matches the value in metadata record then it will do something. However, the requirement is getting bigger and we're adding more metadata record than I expected. My current logic is to loop the metadata record then inside it, loop the object record (this is running in batch).
for(CustomMeta__mdt meta : mdtList) {
    for(Case caseObject : casesList) {
       if(meta.field1__c == caseObject.field1__c){
          // do something
       }
    }
}

Problem is, I realized that my logic is wrong as I can have millions of records.. and this can loop in each metadata record. So I plan to reverse the looping from object record.. then inside it, the custom metadata will loop.
for(Case caseObject : casesList) {
    for(CustomMeta__mdt meta : mdtList) {
       if(meta.field1__c == caseObject.field1__c){
          // do something
       }
    }
}

Beside this, I am thinking if it is better to put the metadata record inside the wrapper class (much like int and Integer) to reduce the parameter in my method as well when referencing this metadata.
Is it better to create a wrapper class or may I encounter unexpected things?
Example:
public class MetadataClass {
  private String field1;
  // other fields goes on..
}

// inside a function loop the metadata records and add in metadataClass list


While a wrapper class can be beneficial1, it's not really going to help you in your case.
The pattern you're using
for(thing 1) {
    for(thing 2) {
        if(thing1.field == thing2.field) {
            // do work
        }
    }
}

is just fundamentally flawed. Without additional context, no matter which order you loop in, the if() in the inner loop is going to be evaluated N * M times. For even modest values of N and M, that's going to add up to a lot of wasted evaluations.
Instead, you should be using a collection type like a Map or Set to contain the data that you're going to be checking against.
Map<String, CustomMeta__mdt> metadataByField1 = new Map<String, CustomMeta__mdt>();

// First loop is used to build the map
// This is done outside of, and before, the main loop
for(CustomMeta__mdt mdtRecord : CustomMetaList) {
    metadataByField1.put(mdtRecord.Field1__c, mdtRecord);
}

// Second loop is then able to use .contains() or .get() to check for the
//   main logic path
for(Case myCase : caseList) {
    CustomMeta__mdt targetMDTRecord = metadataByField.get(myCase.Case_Field1__c);

    // No match in the map ends up with a null value returned
    // Using "continue" here to get to the next iteration of the loop
    //   means your main logic is less indented (which is generally
    //   easier to read, understand, and reason about)
    if(targetMDTRecord == null) { continue; }

    // do work
}

That reduces the number of times that you're looping to N + M
If N = 200 and M = 1000, which are pretty reasonable numbers
That means you're only looping a total of 1,200 times instead of 200,000 times
It's important to note that not all nested loops are evil. It's mostly just the scenario that you currently have where you have if(field1 == field2) inside your inner loop. The real benefit here comes from reducing the total number of times that you're looping.
About the only thing to watch out for is that the data stored in Sets and the key of a Map are case-sensitive. This will take some additional heap space, but it's generally a lot harder to run into that governor limit than it is to run into the CPU time limit.
1: Well, I'm more thinking of a proxy class for the custom metadata type here rather than a wrapper class. Having the extra layer of abstraction (and not accessing the Custom Metadata Type directly) makes it a lot easier to test things that end up using CMT data, especially considering that we cannot insert CMT in tests

+1 for the proxy class (that in turn uses a selector class to fetch the CMDT and hence can be Dependency-injected with mock data)
